# combine two dataframe adding up the values to the corresponding names

Tags: python

How to do the following code?

Dataframe 1

```
             genres1
Drama         1168
Adventure     517
Documentary   431
Animation     353
Crime         335
Romance       328
Sci-Fi        20
```

Dataframe 2

```
            genres2
Comedy       1625
Action       1233
Drama        1200
Documentary  688
Crime        562
Adventure    390
Animation    336
```

could my output be on a new column adding the values altogether, like this

```
              Genre
Drama         2368
Documentary   1119
Adventure     907
Animation     689
Crime         897
Romance       328
Sci-Fi        20
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).fillna(0)
df['Genere'] = df['genres1'] + df['genres2']
df = df.groupby(df.index).sum().drop(['genres1','genres2'],axis=1)
```